# lemonade - countable or uncountable

Tags: uncountable-nouns

Is "lemonade" countable or uncountable? Could I say the following sentence?

> Could you please bring me a lemonade?

Or *must* I say "a glass of lemonade" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Lemonade" is usually uncountable, but it can be used as a countable noun to mean "a  glass of lemonade".  It is uncommon, but possible, to treat "lemonade" as a countable noun.

This applies not only to lemonade but to most beverages.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that this applies not only to lemonade, but to most beverages.

Answer (score 2):

> Or must I say "a glass of lemonade" ?

You don't need to.

From Collins

> A glass of lemonade can be referred to as *a lemonade*. Example: I'm going to get you a lemonade.

Take a look at the following Q and A.

> *What can I get you?*
>
> - A diet coke, please!
> - A can of diet coke, please!

They are both idiomatic. The "a can" or "a glass" is implied.